# Stuck with Next Auth authorize part. Error: Action api with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm getting a strange error for the past few days. Unable to authenticate my Next.js app with credentials.

As far as I know everything is correct according to the doc.

I'm also unable to see a network request in my chrome dev tools.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { signOut,useSession,signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import { axios } from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from "../../../helpers/api/mutations";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "mani@test.com"
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password"
        }},
        // My authorize function where I called my graphql mutation for token and session.
        async authorize(credentials,req) {
            const {data} = await axios({
              url: API_URL,
              method: 'post',
              data: {
               query: `mutation {
                login(
                   mobileNumber: "4738291046",
                  mobileCountryCode: "00",
                  password: "admin123"
                ) {
                  expiresAt
                  accessToken
                }
              }`
              }
             })
              .then(res => {
               console.log(res.data);
              })
              .catch(err => {
               console.log(err.message);
              });

              if (data) {
                console.log(data,'dataaa');
                return data
              }
              else {
                return null
              }
        }
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      // first time jwt callback is run, user object is available
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }

      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
   secret: "test",
   jwt: {
       secret:"test",
       encryption: true,
   },
   pages: {
    signIn: "api/auth/sigin",
  },
});
```

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 15):

It's your file structure. Make sure that `[...nextauth].ts` is in the correct path `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`

Comment: note: using Next 13 app dir, the path should be `app\api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.js`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this because I forgot the leading `/` in my custom signIn page value:

```
pages: {
  signIn: "/api/auth/sigin",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working Solution**

This problem only occur due to these problem listed below

1. It should be "api/auth/signin" not "api/auth/sigin" *Typo Mistake*
2. You api/[auth] folder should be in App directory for Nextjs13 directory and in pages directory in below 13 version of Nextjs

Comment: Suprisingly, the second reason you mentioned is the completely opposite case on my end: 
I have nextjs 13.4.6 running yet i have to put api/[auth]/signup in pages so it will work: 
I can save user to mongodb document with POST request on postman. 

But when i put it in app folder and try to save a user with postman, i get the same error he mentioned above: 
Error: This action with HTTP POST is not supported by NextAuth.js

How is that explained (Sorry to bring more complexity and confusion, but it is a real case for me, i wish it was not)

Comment: Refer this doc. https://hackernoon.com/6-easy-steps-to-use-next-auth-in-nextjs-13-using-route-handler

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading my versions of `next` and `next-auth` to `next@12.3.1` and `next-auth@4.14.0` solved this for me as per this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171248