# next-auth GET /api/auth/session 400 CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR Unexpected token 'E' (Netlify deploy)

Tags: authentication, deployment, netlify, next-auth, dev-to-production

**Problem:**

My next-auth works locally, but when I deploy it to Netlify I get this CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR when accessing anything (RouteGuard component calls useSession hook and pushes to /auth/signin if not authenticated && on non-public path).

> GET https://website.com/api/auth/session 400
> --> Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js
>
> [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token 'E', "Error:
> Thi"... is not valid JSON
>
> POST https://website.com/api/auth/_log 400

Locally it calls http://localhost:4200/api/auth/session and returns 304 with {}.

**Where the useSession hook is called:**

_app > Session Provider session={session} > RouteGuard

**Expected API returns as per documentation:**

*https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession*

> When called, getSession() will send a request to /api/auth/session and
> returns a promise with a session object, or null if no session exists.

*https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthsession*

> Returns client-safe session object - or an empty object if there is no session.
> The contents of the session object that is returned are configurable with the session callback.

**Session callback:**

```
async session({ session, token, user }) {

  session.accessToken = token.accessToken
  session.user._id = token.sub
  session.user.name = token.name
  session.user.email = token.email
  if (token.login_provider) session.user.login_provider = token.login_provider
  return session

}
```

**What I have already checked locally and on Netlify:**

- [...nextauth].ts is correctly placed in /pages/api/auth folder
- it is correctly named exactly as I have written above
- NEXTAUTH_URL is correctly set (not using any custom basePath)
- Using Next.js Runtime - v4.27.3 also sets this automatically, though it makes no difference how it is set
- NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL is correctly set (same url + /api)
- NEXTAUTH_SECRET is correctly set
- NextAuthOptions object's pages: { signIn: '/auth/signin' } is correct
- /pages/auth/signin page is placed and named correctly
- Credentials, Google and Facebook provider env vars are set correctly

> ```
> "next": "11.1.0",
> "next-auth": "^4.6.1",
> ```

**What else should I check?**

Been Googling, reading docs, re-reading docs and trying everything to no avail for a day now...

Please help /o\

**Update:**

- did some more research and I don't know if it matters, but the request on localhost is sent with cookies, while these cookies aren't sent on the deployed version:

> next-auth.csrf-token

> next-auth.callback-url

**Update 2:**

- getProviders does not work in getServerSideProps on Netlify because it doesn't like SSR I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using exact versions of next@12.3.1 and next-auth@4.14.0.

Found the solution here: https://answers.netlify.com/t/nexauth-returning-action-not-found/77779/5