# Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.jsv

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have tried many things, and my current versions of NEXT.JS and NEXTauth are up to date.
However, an error always appears. The error doesnt make sense to me anymore...

Error: `Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js`

Versions:

"next": "13.0.1",
"next-auth": "^4.22.1",

My page: pages/api/[...nextauth].jsx

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

const options = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        // Implemente sua lógica de autenticação aqui
        if (credentials.username === 'jonas' && credentials.password === '123') {
          return Promise.resolve(credentials)
        } else {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Credenciais inválidas'))
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  methods: ['POST'],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login' // Página de login personalizada
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user, account, profile) {
      // Adicione aqui qualquer lógica personalizada que você queira executar após o login bem-sucedido
      return Promise.resolve(true)
    },
    async redirect(url, baseUrl) {
      // Redirecionamento personalizado após o login
      return Promise.resolve(baseUrl)
    },
    async session(session, user) {
      // Aqui você pode adicionar ou modificar dados da sessão do usuário
      session.user = user
      return Promise.resolve(session)
    },
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      // Aqui você pode adicionar ou modificar dados no token JWT
      return Promise.resolve(token)
    }
  }
}

const Auth = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options)

export default Auth
```

My Login page pages/login.jsx -  I have set a static login with my name, but it still doesn't work.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useSession, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function LoginPage() {
  const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession()
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ username: '', password: '' })
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      ...credentials
    })

    if (result.error) {
      // Tratar erro de autenticação
      console.error(result.error)
    } else {
      // Redirecionar para a página principal após o login bem-sucedido
      router.push('/')
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  if (sessionStatus === 'loading') {
    return <div>Carregando...</div>
  }

  if (session) {
    router.push('/')
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck with Next Auth authorize part. Error: Action api with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71017926/stuck-with-next-auth-authorize-part-error-action-api-with-http-get-is-not-supp)

Comment: I do:

My next-auth.config.js

module.exports = {
  providers: [
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/api/auth/signin",
  },
};

My files:

pages/api/auth [...nextauth].jsx 
pages/api/auth signin.tsx
pages/login.jsx