# "Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js" signIn function not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0

Trying to set up a static login in page for my project using Auth.js SignIn function but for some reason it returns the error in the title, unsure of the issue.

Pages > API > Auth > [nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth ({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type:"text", placeholder: 'user'},
                password: { label: "Password",  type:"text", placeholder:'password'},
            },

            async authorize(credentials) {
                if (credentials == null) return null; {
                    //login
                    const { username, password } = credentials;
                    if (!user) {
                        console.log('user is not found!')
                    }
                    const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
                    if(!isMatch) {
                        throw new Error("Username or Password is incorrect")
                    }
                    return user;
                }
            
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
            const isAllowedToSignIn = true
            if (isAllowedToSignIn) { 
            return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    },
    async redirect({url, baseUrl}) {
        // Allows relative callback URLs
        if(url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
        // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
        else if ( new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
        return baseUrl
    },
    async session({session, user, token}) {
        return session
    },
    async jwt({token, user, account, profile, isNewUser}) {
        return token
    },
        pages: {
            signIn: '/login.jsx',
        },

    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.id = user._id.toString(); // Convert ObjectID to string
            }
        }
    }

})
```

Login.jsx file

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Link from 'next/link';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Spacer } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {signIn} from "next-auth/react"

const Login = () => {
    const  [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault(e);
       console.log(user);
       console.log(pass);
       signIn();
       
       if (!user) {
        window.alert('Please provide username')
       }
       else if (!pass) {
        window.alert('Please provide password')
       } else {
        window.alert('Welcome' + ' ' + {user})
        router.push('../user-pages/profile')
       } 

    }

   

        return (
            <div className="authform">
            <div className="form">
                
           <form>
                <Spacer y={1} />
            <input name="userName"/>
            <label style={{color: "white", translate: -5}} form="userName">
                Username
                <input value={user} onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)} type='username' placeholder='Username' id="Username" name='Username'/>
            </label>
           
            <Spacer y= {.25} />
                <br />
            <label style={{color: "White", translate: -5}} form="Password">Password</label>
            <input value={pass} onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)}type="Password" placeholder="******" id='Password' name='Password' />

            <button type='submit' 
            onClick={signIn}>Log In</button>
           </form>
           <Spacer y={.75} />
           <a style={{color: "white"}} href='#'>Forgot Password?</a>
                <Spacer y={.25} />
           <Link style={{color: "white"}} href='../user-pages/signup'> Dont have an account? Register here! </Link>
           </div>
           </div>
        );
    };
 
export default Login;
```

Attempted to use the signIn function to authourize the user session using a handlesubmit function, instead I receieve a http error

Comment: Have you read [this](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3107) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71017926/stuck-with-next-auth-authorize-part-error-action-api-with-http-get-is-not-supp) as part of researching the issue? There's many more links with similar issues with solutions, you just have to search the internets with the quoted part in the title of this question

Comment: I have! none of the solutions have done me justice

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed the above issue as below. Please make sure that you have callback uri format ***/api/auth/callback/provider-unique-id***

```
// "next": "14.0.4",
// "next-auth": "^4.24.5",

import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

// Please replace all the endpoint & env variables with yours 

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [{
        id: "provider-unique-id",
        name: "provider-description",
        type: "oauth",
        version: "2.0",
        state: true,
        authorization: {
            url: authorizeUrl,
            params: {
                scope: SCOPES.join(','),
                redirect_uri: APP_OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL,
            },
        },
        clientId: process.env.PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET,
        userinfo: userProfileUrl,
        token: {
            url: accessToken
        },
        issuer: {
            token_endpoint: accessTokenUrl,
            userinfo_endpoint: userProfileUrl
        },
        profile(userInfo, tokens) {
            return {
                id: userInfo.id,
                name: userInfo.name,
                phoneNumber: userInfo.phone_number,
            }
        }
    }],
    callbacks: {
        session: ({ session, token: { account, user } }) => {
            session.user.id = user?.id;
            session.accessToken = account?.access_token;
            session.provider = account?.provider;
            return session
        },
        jwt: ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user
            }
            if (account) {
                token.account = account
            }
            return token
        }
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/signin'
    }
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```